# Why is Google App Engine Making --set-default a default parameter?

Tags: google-app-engine

So, in the past, when I've used Google App Engine, I've utilized their wonderful version system to create an integration, staging, and production environment. When we're ready to go live, we set the production environment to be the default, and it starts receiving traffic at the standard AppSpot URL (`myapp.appspot.com`), if it's not the default you have to manually go to the version itself (`dev.myapp.appspot.com`) for your testing. This is an awesome system for a pre-prod deployment with a full test.

However, I just went to do an App Engine deployment today and got this warning:

```
WARNING: Soon, deployments will set the deployed version to receive all traffic by
default.

To keep the current behavior (where new deployments do not receive any traffic),
use the `--no-promote` flag or run the following command:

  $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false

To adopt the new behavior early, use the `--promote` flag or run the following
command:

  $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default true

Either passing one of the new flags or setting one of these properties will
silence this message.
```

So, apparently, very soon Google will make it so that for every deploy of any version, they will just automatically promote that to be the default and be accessible at the standard AppSpot URL.

My question is, what's the benefit in this? I can't use this for A/B testing (since there's no B in the equation here). I can't use this as a pre-prod test, because it takes over my environment right away. Why would I want any version I push up to be the default? Am I missing something? Was I using versions wrong?

I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: I thought it an unusual change too, but can you not just do `gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false` and carry on as normal?  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: It wasn't a, "how do I fix this" question, as I figured that out quickly enough. It's more of a thought experiment on how Google expects this default change to be useful to anyone, or how someone would benefit from a change like this.